# How to view the SQL Server transaction log on AWS RDS?

Tags: sql-server, sql

Is it possible to see the T-SQL Query log in AWS RDS? is there a UI for that in the console, or i need to use the CLI or SQL Management Studio?

Comment: What exactly do you want to see?  The actual contents of the transaction log or a trace of activity?

Comment: I want to see the SQL statements that were executed last.

Answer (score 2):

To view SQL statements that were executed you can do a trace.  [**This link**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.SQLServer.html) explains what you need to do to do a trace in AWS RDS.

From the documentation:

**Generating a Trace SQL Query**

```
declare @rc int 
declare @TraceID int 
declare @maxfilesize bigint 
set @maxfilesize = 5
exec @rc = sp_trace_create @TraceID output,  0, N'D:\rdsdbdata\rdstest', @maxfilesize, NULL
```

**Viewing an Open Trace**

```
select * from ::fn_trace_getinfo(default)
```

**Viewing Trace Contents**

```
select * from ::fn_trace_gettable('D:\rdsdbdata\rdstest.trc', default)
```

You will also want to familiarize yourself with SQL Traces if you are not already.  There are several options available to you for capturing data.

Comment: Worth mentioning that you need to be careful with traces.  Running them on production can be very intensive and bring the SQL instance to a halt.  Be judicious when running a trace and as selective as possible with the events that you want to trace.

Comment: That's a hard lesson that I learned in my early days as a DBA. :)